# Is it possible to install my app on a real device iPhone with iOS 12.5.5 with Xcode 13.3 running on a M1 Mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, apple-m1

Unfortunately I'm not able to download an iOS 12.x simulator on my new Mac with M1 chip. But I need a debug device with iOS<13.0. So does it make sense to buy an old iPhone (e.g. 6s) with iOS 12.5.5?

Comment: We are programmers, not economists. Buy what makes sense to buy. Please restrict your use of Stack Overflow to programming questions.

Comment: I am an advocate of testing on physical devices, regardless. I’ve built my motley collection of old devices by asking for hand-me-down’s (and not trading-in my own devices). I label them with device/iOS version info and disable “automatic updates”. But if you can’t wait for someone in your network to bequeath one to you and you decide to purchase one, you can also save a little money if you buy one with cosmetic defects. It has to work, but doesn’t have to be pretty. But reach out to your personal network first: A family member may well have an old device sitting in a drawer somewhere…